# git rebase confusion

Tags: git, branch, rebase

let's say if I have 2 branches
`topic` and `master`
if I am on `topic` branch, and run `git rebase master` does it rebase master or rebase topic branch?

doing `git rebase --help` gave me this

Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":

```
             A---B---C topic
            /
       D---E---F---G master
```

From this point, the result of either of the following commands:

```
       git rebase master
       git rebase master topic
```

would be:

```
                         A'--B'--C' topic
                        /
           D---E---F---G master
```

NOTE: The latter form is just a short-hand of git checkout topic followed by git rebase master. When rebase exits topic will remain the checked-out branch.

And if I want to achieve this `D---E---F---G---A---B---C master`, should I switch to master and run `git rebase -i topic`?

And if I run `git rebase -i topic` try to squash A,B,C to C to become `D---E---F---G---C master`, I get `noop`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What do you want the tree to look like when you're done?

Comment: according to the manual (see above), it seems to be other way round?

Comment: Are you trying to pull changes from `topic` into `master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you start out with a tree that looks like this

```
         A---B---C topic
        /
   D---E---F---G master
```

You'll want to run 2 commands `git rebase master` to make it look like this

```
                     A'--B'--C' topic
                    /
   D---E---F---G master
```

then from `master` run `git merge topic`, which will do a fast forward merge, and you'll end up with a tree that looks like this

```
                             topic
                            /
   D---E---F---G---A---B---C -- master
```

---

> Can I just checkout master and run *git rebase topic*??

Running that command would result in a tree that looks like this

```
                             topic
                            /
   D---A---B---C---E---F---G -- master
```

---

This is the (somewhat edited) git documentation for `rebase`, hopefully this will help:

> All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in *upstream* are saved to a temporary area.

If you are on `topic` and run `git rebase master`, that means commits A, B and C are going into a temporary area.

> The current branch is reset to *upstream*. This has the exact same effect as git reset --hard *upstream*.

At this point the temporary state of the tree looks like this

```
                 topic
                /
   D---E---F---G -- master
```

> The commits that were previously saved into the temporary area are then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order.

Commits A, B, C that were saved into the temporary area are "recommitted" to the branch you are currently on `topic`.

```
                             topic
                            /
   D---E---F---G---A---B---C -- master
```

Running `git rebase topic` from `master` would perform the exact same steps, except instead of putting commits A, B, C into the temporary area, it would put commits E, F G into the temporary area.

Comment: is this the only way to achieve D---E---F---G---A---B---C master via rebase?? Can I just checkout master and run `git rebase topic`??

Comment: i see, that makes a lot of sense, so should I first rebase on local topic branch to squash commits, then merge the change onto master and then push?

Comment: Yes, you'd clean up history on your topic branch, then merge back into master.